# Parameter specified as non-null is null : kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-asynctask, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to upload image to website, It was successful but app shows FETAL error.

issue seems like in AsyncTask as it might get executed to early.

I also upgraded SDK version 30 to 32
& ucrop:2.2.5

```
package com.myappname.dating.ui.home.profileImageUploading

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.myappname.dating.R
import com.myappname.dating.data.db.CrushDataBase
import com.myappname.dating.data.network.ApiHelper
import com.myappname.dating.data.network.model.profileRespo.ProfileStatus
import com.myappname.dating.data.network.model.user.Mediafile
import com.myappname.dating.data.network.model.user.UserResponse
import com.myappname.dating.data.pref.AppPreferencesHelper
import com.myappname.dating.ui.login.LoginActivity
import com.myappname.dating.ui.utils.AppConstants
import com.myappname.dating.ui.utils.CommonUtil
import com.yalantis.ucrop.UCrop
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_user_image_crop.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_user_image_crop.pb_load
import okhttp3.MediaType.Companion.toMediaTypeOrNull
import okhttp3.MultipartBody
import okhttp3.RequestBody
import okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.asRequestBody
import okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.toRequestBody
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import java.io.File


@Suppress("NULLABILITY_MISMATCH_BASED_ON_JAVA_ANNOTATIONS")
class UserImageCropActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener, CropImageView {

    internal val IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 123
    internal val CROP_IMAGE_NAME = "cropImage"
    private lateinit var mImageCropPresenter : ImageCropPresenter
    lateinit var from : String
    var imageUriResultCrop: Uri? = null
    var uriString: String? = null
    lateinit var mPref: AppPreferencesHelper
    var mCrushDataBase: CrushDataBase? = null
    lateinit var userResponse: UserResponse;

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState : Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_image_crop)
        mPref = AppPreferencesHelper(applicationContext, AppConstants.PREF_NAME)
        val view: View = findViewById(R.id.imageCropActivity)
        mCrushDataBase = CrushDataBase.getDatabase(this)

        mImageCropPresenter = ImageCropPresenterImpl(this, this, view)

        if(intent != null){
            from = intent.getStringExtra("From").toString()
        }
        if(from.equals("Signup")){
            //Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            userResponse = getDataTask(this).execute().get()
        }


        val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
        galleryIntent.type = "image/*"
        if(galleryIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Picture"),
                IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE
            )
        }
        uploadBtn.setOnClickListener(this)
    }


    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            val imageUri = data?.data
            if (imageUri != null) {
                startCrop(imageUri)
            } else {
                uploadBtn.visibility = View.GONE
                finish()
//                if (from == "") {
//
//                }
//                else if(from == "")
//                {
//
//                }
            }
        } else {
            imageUriResultCrop = data?.let { UCrop.getOutput(it) }
            uriString = imageUriResultCrop?.path

            if (imageUriResultCrop != null) {
                result_image.setImageURI(imageUriResultCrop)
                uploadBtn.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            } else {
                uploadBtn.visibility = View.GONE
                finish()
            }
        }
    }


    private fun startCrop(uri: Uri) {
        var destinationFileName = CROP_IMAGE_NAME
        destinationFileName += ".jpg"

        val uCrop = UCrop.of(uri, Uri.fromFile(File(cacheDir, destinationFileName)))
        uCrop.withAspectRatio(1F, 1F)
        uCrop.withMaxResultSize(800, 800)
        uCrop.withOptions(getCropOptions())
        uCrop.start(this)
    }

    private fun getCropOptions() : UCrop.Options {
        val options = UCrop.Options()
        options.setHideBottomControls(false)
        options.setFreeStyleCropEnabled(true)

        options.setStatusBarColor(resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
        options.setToolbarColor(resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))

        return options
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when (v?.id) {
            R.id.uploadBtn -> {
                if (uriString == null || uriString == "") {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "please select an image ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                    return
                } else {
                    val file = File(imageUriResultCrop?.path)
                    val requestFile = file.asRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())
                    val body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("avater", file.name, requestFile)
                    val accessToken: String? = mPref.getAccessToken()
                    val requestBody = accessToken?.toRequestBody(MultipartBody.FORM)
                    if (from.equals("Signup")){
                        updateAvater(requestBody,body)
                    }else if(from.equals("ProfileAct")){
                        updateAvaterp(requestBody,body)
                    }else if(from.equals("userImage")){
                        updateAvaterG(requestBody,body)
                    }else if(from.equals("userImageD")){
                        updateAvaterGal(requestBody,body)
                    }
                    else{
                    mImageCropPresenter.imageCropUploadPresenter(requestBody, body)
                    }
                }
                uploadBtn.isClickable = false
                uploadBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e4e6e8"))

            }
        }
    }

    fun updateAvaterp(
        access_token: RequestBody?,
        avater: MultipartBody.Part
    ) {
        ApiHelper().updateAvaterImage(access_token, avater)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<ProfileStatus> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<ProfileStatus>, t: Throwable) {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Failed to upload please select another image or check internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                    uploadBtn.isClickable = true
                    uploadBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2196f3"))
                }

                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<ProfileStatus>,
                    response: Response<ProfileStatus>
                ) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {

                        val updateCheck = UpdateTaskA(
                            this@UserImageCropActivity, response.body()!!.picurl, userResponse.id ).execute().get()

                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Profile Upload Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        finish()
                    }
                }
            })
    }
    fun updateAvaterG(
        access_token: RequestBody?,
        avater: MultipartBody.Part
    ) {
        ApiHelper().updateAvaterImage(access_token, avater)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<ProfileStatus> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<ProfileStatus>, t: Throwable) {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Failed to upload please select another image or check internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                }

                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<ProfileStatus>,
                    response: Response<ProfileStatus>
                ) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {

                        val updateCheck = UpdateTaskG(this@UserImageCropActivity, response.body()!!.picurl, userResponse!!.id ).execute().get()

                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Profile Upload Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        finish()
                    }
                }
            })
    }
    fun updateAvaterGal(
        access_token: RequestBody?,
        avater: MultipartBody.Part
    ) {
        ApiHelper().uploadImage(access_token, avater)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<ProfileStatus> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<ProfileStatus>, t: Throwable) {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Failed to upload please select another image or check internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                }

                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<ProfileStatus>,
                    response: Response<ProfileStatus>
                ) {if (response.isSuccessful) {
                       // val updateCheck = UpdateTaskG(this@UserImageCropActivity, response.body()!!.picurl, userResponse!!.id ).execute().get()

                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Image Upload Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                       // finish()
                      // var lnk =  response.body()!!.file_url
                     //   response.body().picurl

                        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, UserImageGalleryActivity::class.java)
                       // intent.putExtra("fileurl", lnk)
                       // intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                        startActivity(intent)

                        //startActivity(Intent(this, UserImageGalleryActivity::class.java))
                    }
                }
            })
    }
    fun updateAvater(
        access_token: RequestBody?,
        avater: MultipartBody.Part
    ) {
        ApiHelper().updateAvaterImage(access_token, avater)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<ProfileStatus> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<ProfileStatus>, t: Throwable) {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Failed to upload please select another image or check internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                }

                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<ProfileStatus>,
                    response: Response<ProfileStatus>
                ) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, LoginActivity::class.java)
                        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                        startActivity(intent)
                        finish()
                    }
                }
            })
    }
    override fun showProgressBar() {
        pb_load.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    override fun hideProgressBar() {
        pb_load.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    override fun onSuccess(id: String) {
        var  value: List<Mediafile>


     // val updateCheck = UpdateTask(this,map).execute().get()

        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Image Upload Successfully$id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        finish()
    }

    override fun onFailure(message: String) {
        Toast.makeText(
            applicationContext,
            "Image not upload Something went wrong"+message,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
        finish()
    }

    override fun backToActivity() {
        val intent =
            Intent(applicationContext, UserImageGalleryActivity::class.java)
        intent.flags =
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mImageCropPresenter.onDestroy()
    }



    private class UpdateTask(var context: UserImageCropActivity, var  value: List<Mediafile>?) :
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Boolean {

            context.mCrushDataBase!!.crushDao().updateMediaFile(value, 1)
            return true
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(bool: Boolean?) {
            if (bool!!) {
            }
        }
    }


    class UpdateTaskA(var context: UserImageCropActivity, var avatar: String,var id : Int) :
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Boolean {

            val imageAvatar = CommonUtil.convertToString64(avatar)
            context.mCrushDataBase!!.crushDao().updateAvatar(imageAvatar!!, id)
            return true
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(bool: Boolean?) {
            if (bool!!) {
            }
        }
    }
    class UpdateTaskG(var context: UserImageCropActivity, var avatar: String, var user: Int) :
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Boolean {
            val imageAvatar = CommonUtil.convertToString64(avatar)

            context.mCrushDataBase!!.crushDao().updateAvatar(imageAvatar!!, user)
            return true
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(bool: Boolean?) {
            if (bool!!) {
            }
        }
    }


     class getDataTask(var context: UserImageCropActivity) :
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, UserResponse>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): UserResponse {
            var listOfdata = context.mCrushDataBase!!.crushDao().getData()
            val data = listOfdata[0]
            return data
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(userResponse: UserResponse?) {
        }
    }

}
```

Error was displayed in line

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: com.myappname.dating, PID: 17170
     java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter,
 parameter avatar
         at com.myappname.dating.ui.home.profileImageUploading.UserImageCropActivity$UpdateTaskA.<init>(Unknown
 Source:7)
         at com.myappname.dating.ui.home.profileImageUploading.UserImageCropActivity$updateAvaterp$1.onResponse(UserImageCropActivity.kt:190)
```

Comment: response.body() is null maybe your response is not correctly serialized to your model

Comment: Actually this code was working till android 30 Now I moved to Android version 32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stacktrace is saying that you're passing *null* for the `avatar` parameter in the `UpdateTaskA` constructor, which is being called from the `onResponse` function inside `UpdateAvaterp`

```
// avatar is a String, not a String? so it can't be null
class UpdateTaskA(var context: UserImageCropActivity, var avatar: String,var id : Int)
```

```
// inside your on onResponse function
UpdateTaskA(this@UserImageCropActivity, response.body()!!.picurl, userResponse.id )
```

So you're passing `response.body()!!.picurl` as your `avatar` parameter, but it's null. So your response doesn't have that value. You either need to handle the possibility that it's *null*, or if that should never happen (which is a risky assumption when calling an API that could change) then you need to work out what the problem is with the network call and fix it.

Easiest way is probably setting a breakpoint inside `onResponse` and inspecting the response to see what it contains, and if there's any info about why you're not getting the data you want. If you haven't used the debugger before, [here's an overview](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/) - it can save you a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

Also as AsyncTask is long ago deprecated https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/base/+/1156409 I suggest to not to use it.

Instead you can use `java.util.concurrent.Executors` or just Kotlin Coroutines to handle doing stuff asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to use **non-null assertion operator `!!`** in places where a variable can be `null`. There is a **safe call operator `?.`** for that purpose:

```
val pictureUrl = response.body()?.picurl
pictureUrl?.let { picurl ->
    // Execute this block of code only when `pictureUrl` is not null
        val updateCheck = UpdateTaskA(
        this@UserImageCropActivity, 
        picurl, 
        userResponse.id 
    ).execute().get()
}
```